# Add Array to Session by form Submit

Tags: php, html, arrays, function, session-variables

I'm trying to add a Array to a Multi-Array in a session (by array_push). The Array is filled with variables of a html form. Here's the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['warenkorb'] = array();

echo("
<form>
    Anzahl: <input style='width: 60px;' type='number' name='anzahl' required/>
    <input type='submit' value='Hinzufügen' onclick='add(".$item["id"]. ", anzahl)'/>
</form>
");

function add($id, $amount) {
    echo "$amount of $id";
}
```

I used "echo" in the add function to see, if it works. But theres no output and no error message. How can this be fixed?

Comment: You're confusing JS with PHP here; use ajax. What you tried will not work as is.

Comment: `onclick='add()'` will call ajavascript function, which I don't see.

Comment: How can you expect `onclick` to get react with `php` ?